# r aggregate max when by parameter is based on multiple columns

Tags: r, max, aggregate, subset

I have a dataset as follows

```
 Id       Date         Subject       Score
 12221    08/01/2007  Math          89
 12221    08/01/2007  Math          92
 12221    08/01/2007  Math          78
 12221    11/01/2007  Math          36
 12221    11/01/2007  Math          45
 12221    11/01/2007  Math          24
 2856     03/18/2004  Science       56
 2856     03/18/2004  Science       49
 2856     03/18/2004  Science       84
```

I am trying to retain only rows where the Score is maximum for a combination of Id, Date and Subject for example the final output should look like this below

```
 Id       Date         Subject       Score
 12221    08/01/2007  Math          92
 12221    11/01/2007  Math          45
 2856     03/18/2004  Science       84
```

I tried `aggregate` function,

```
aggregate(score ~ list(Id,Date,Subject), df, max)
```

this did not work, tried `dcast` , `which.max` etc neither of these are producing the desired results, any help on resolving this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use aggregate

```
aggregate(Score~., df1, FUN= max)
#        Id       Date Subject Score
#1 12221 08/01/2007    Math    92
#2 12221 11/01/2007    Math    45
#3  2856 03/18/2004 Science    84
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Id, Date, Subject) %>%
   summarise(Score= max(Score))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Score= max(Score)), by = .(Id, Date, Subject)]
```